# C1 CMS - IIS WebSocket support installed Error on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, c1-cms

Spinning up **C1 CMS** for the first time with Microsoft Azure, getting below error and could not proceed here after.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Move to your **Application Settings** on your application on **Azure** and switch below. 
[image]